# JakartaSever Faces application setup fails with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.Util

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm in the process of setting up a brand new JavaServer Faces project that uses Jakarta. I'm following [this](https://blog.payara.fish/getting-started-with-jakarta-ee-9-jakarta-faces-jsf) as a guide, and while I understand the problem with the stacktrace, I can't understand why (the new) Jakarta Faces implementation is asking me for an old dependency.

This is what I have in the `pom.xml` file (simplified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ...>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <jakarta.platform.version>9.1.0</jakarta.platform.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakarta.platform.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.0</version>
        <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
      </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>11.0.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
              <version>${jakarta.platform.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the `web.xml` file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

> **TIP**: I'm running the application with `./mvnw clean jetty:run`.

This is the entire stacktrace:

```sh
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/faces/util/Util
    at jakarta.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder (CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:52)
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory (FactoryFinder.java:260)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory (FacesServlet.java:483)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init (FacesServlet.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$Wrapper.init (ServletHolder.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize (ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2 (ServletHandler.java:690)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end (SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining (StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining (Streams.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenWebAppContext.doStart (MavenWebAppContext.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyEmbedder.doStart (JettyEmbedder.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.startJettyEmbedded (JettyRunMojo.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.startJetty (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.execute (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.util.Util
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at jakarta.faces.CurrentThreadToServletContext.getFactoryFinder (CurrentThreadToServletContext.java:52)
    at jakarta.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory (FactoryFinder.java:260)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.acquireFacesContextFactory (FacesServlet.java:483)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init (FacesServlet.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$Wrapper.init (ServletHolder.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize (ServletHolder.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$2 (ServletHandler.java:690)
    at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end (SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining (StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining (Streams.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenWebAppContext.doStart (MavenWebAppContext.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyEmbedder.doStart (JettyEmbedder.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.startJettyEmbedded (JettyRunMojo.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.startJetty (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractWebAppMojo.execute (AbstractWebAppMojo.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@72b2c5ed{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started Server@57f8951a{STARTING}[11.0.7,sto=0] @2371ms
[INFO] Scan interval sec = 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to include some Jakara Faces implementation, and in this case, the easiest one would be the Mojarra because you are using the standard Jakarta Faces API that already requires some classes from the Mojarra implementation.

You can checkout all the required dependencies here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra

If you want to use the Myfaces, you'll need to replace the standard Jakarta Faces API for the Jakata Faces API provided by them.

Comment: MyFaces is exactly the same as easy as Mojarra ;)

Comment: I thought that including `jakarta.platform:jakarta.jakartaee-web-api` was enough to include the default implementation, unless it's `optional`.

Comment: Nops :) The web-api is a jar that includes only the API, not any implementation of it. It is great when using a lot of spec, like JPA, JSF, Servlets, because you have only one provided dependency, but you have to deploy it to some application server.

Comment: In your case, you are using the web-api jar and not providing any implementation, because the Jetty supports only a few specs, like Servlets and EL IIRC

Comment: You are right. Including those dependencies in the guide solved the problem! On the other hand, if I use WildFly (or any other supported application server) nothing else needs to be provided — looks like they are shipping by default some implementations. It's been a while since I don't deal with any Application Servers ;)

Comment: Very bad design anyway... the `jakarta.faces:jakarta.faces-api`, which should contain the Faces API, use classes that are located in `org.glassfish:jakarta.faces`, which is just an implementation...

Answer (score 1):

I just want to note that the solution posted by @ThiagoHenriqueHupner in Dec 28, 2021 at 11:55 works fine for me. (I don't have de reputation to vote).

Th next link is the Mojarra implementation for Jakarta Faces v4 in the Maven Central Repo

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces

An other alternative is using a EE compatible application server:

For Jakarta EE:
https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/

For Java EE:
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/compatibility-jsp.html

If you really need Myfaces i could suggest to try different versions (upwards and downwards) of Myfaces implementation bundle.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-bundle

And as last resource, if you project compiles and executes using MyFaces, TEST EXTENSIVE AND INSTENSIVE ALL THE PROJECT, probably you don't use the "Util" so you could be fine. I know the last one is not a real solution, but hey, is an idea.